# Using disabledDate in Antd Datepicker in table

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { version, DatePicker, Table } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import moment from "moment";

function disabledDate(current) {
  const now = moment();
  return (
    current &&
    (current < now.subtract(1, "day") || current > now.add(6, "months"))
  );
}

const columns = [
  {
    title: "date",
    dataIndex: "date",
    render: text => {
      return <DatePicker disabledDate={disabledDate} value={moment(text)} />;
    }
  }
];

const dataSource = [
  {
    key: "1",
    date: 1582863300000
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    date: 1583761200000
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <div className="App">
    <p>antd version:{version}</p>
    <Table columns={columns} dataSource={dataSource} />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I'm using Antd Datepicker, and I want users can only select today and not after 6 months.But in table, the first row is okay, the second one can select yesterday.
Here is the codesandbox link:https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-u1edz

Answer (score 2):

It is not a problem with `DatePicker` as if you set the same two dates you will see the same result, the problem is with the second date you supply and with `disabledDate` logic.

```
const dataSource = [
  {
    key: '1',
    date: 1582863300000
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    // set the same date and see no diff date: 1582863300000
    date: 1583761200000
  }
];
```

As I understand, you want to implement the next logic:

```
today <= can be selected <= today + 6 months
```

Which is:

```
function disabledDate(current) {
  const now = moment();
  return (
    current && (now.endOf('day') > current || current > now.add(6, 'months'))
  );
}
```

[image: Edit antd reproduction template]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!So the `current < now.subtract(1, "day") ` is not suitable for this case? Why is that? Does it have something to do with the timezone?

Comment: It's ok but not the logic you described "users can only select today"